# Why my Windows 11 PC hibernates despite of these settings?

Tags: windows-11, sleep, hibernate

Here are the power settings of my Intel N100 mini-PC running Windows 11 Pro:

[image]

The PC hibernates after a few hours. Is there any other setting I missed to prevent it from hibernating?

Comment: Hibernate != Sleep

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a GUI option to disable hibernation?

Comment: I added the method to add Hibernation to Power Options and deal with Hibernation from the Power Options GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning hibernation OFF.

From an Admin Command prompt:   **powercfg.exe /hibernate off**    and press Enter to continue.

Restart and test

You can show Hibernation in Power Settings (Control Panel) and then have a regular GUI method to manage Hibernation.

If you just wish to disable and forget it, use the command line once, and it is all done.

Please see below:

[image: Add Hibernation to Power Options]

Comment: Command line method worked, but my Windows doesn't have the screen you are showing. The closest is Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options -> System Settings, but it doesn't have Hibernate check box.